# Where do I store a hash securely on my Mac mini?

Tags: encryption

So I just got my first Computer with MacOS (never used MacOS, idk anything). I am trying to make a password manager which stores all my data (usernames, emails, passwords etc.) so I only need to remember one MasterPassword.

All the Data is AES encrypted with that MasterPassword and the hash of that Password is currently stored in a .txt file. Now I am thinking: What if someone just puts his own hash into that file and just logs into the program ?

How do I store this hash safely?

Comment: Just use an existing solution. For one, storing a password hash will be of absolutely no use for you.

Comment: what do you mean by existing solution?

Comment: https://keepass.info/

Comment: Mac OS X comes with the [Keychain](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-keychains-to-store-passwords-mchlf375f392/mac) application. You can use it as a password manager and store other secrets in it

Answer (score 1):

In general, the number one rule of crypto is ["never roll your own crypto"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). (never write your own system to be secure when somebody else has already written one.) There are a number of reasons for this, but the most obvious is that even if you are very smart, an established package will have had more smart eyes on it to patch any security issues you might have missed.

**If you want to safely store your data, use a password manager that is well-established.**

If you want to make a password manager as a personal project though, here are some things to consider.

- The most secure way to store a hash is to not store it at all. If you're AES encrypting your data, the way to verify that it has been decrypted is that the decrypted plaintext is correct. That way, you don't need to store anything regarding the password at all.
- You want to [salt your hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) so that common passwords do not lead to common hashes. The SHA-512 sum for `password` is `9151440965cf9c5e07f81eee6241c042a7b78e9bb2dd4f928a8f6da5e369cdffdd2b70c70663ee30d02115731d35f1ece5aad9b362aaa9850efa99e3d197212a`. [Here are the google search results for that string](https://www.google.com/search?q=9151440965cf9c5e07f81eee6241c042a7b78e9bb2dd4f928a8f6da5e369cdffdd2b70c70663ee30d02115731d35f1ece5aad9b362aaa9850efa99e3d197212a). If we instead hash `password+EsistDerPascal K` we get a string that returns no google search results. See the link for standard hashing techniques.
- Use a proper cryptographic hash. While [many things still use SHA-512](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features) others have moved to [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or other algorithms. If you're here from the future and Ubuntu isn't using SHA-512, don't use it.
- You want your hash ([and salt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt)) to be only readable by users who should be able to use it. The easiest thing here is probably using `chmod 600` to restrict read/write of the file to your user (or another user, or root).

This is an incomplete list and you should not rely upon any of the above to protect sensitive information.

Comment: SHA-2 is not a password hashing algorithm. It’s dangerous to even mention it in the same sentence. Use BCrypt or SCrypt or Argo.

Comment: BCrypt, SCrypt, and Argo don't have the amount of google-searchable rainbow tables that SHA-2 does, so it's not quite as illustrative. I've added a bullet point below that says "don't use them" though, you're right. Thank you.